# Wordpress wp-admin Could not retrieve data error

Tags: wordpress, authentication, wp-admin

If I go to my Wordpress website everything is fine but if I want to login in wp-admin. I get an error saying "Could not retrieve data" in a blank page.

I already tried to delete any recently installed plugins but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing plugins step by step, this might be caused by an update of on older plugin you already had installed before.

This seems to be a error message provided from a plugin. What I would do I would checkout this project locally and search trough the plugins directory for this error message. The file that provides the error message will be in the plugin directory that is causing the problem. After that I would disable or remove the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the wp-content/plugins directory to something like wp-content/plugins2 using FTP or CPanel File Manager. Then access your admin dashboard wp-admin/index.php. If you can access the admin dashboard, then you can rename plugins directory back and check your plugins that causing the problem.